# Write $\frac {1}{1+z^2}$ as a power series centered at $z_0=1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, geometric-series

I'm trying to solve a question where I need to write $\frac {1}{1+z^2} $ as a power series centered at $z_0=1$

I'm not allowed to use taylor expansion. So my first thought was to rewrite the function in a form where I can apply the basic identity:

$$ \frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n $$

So let's rewrite the original function $f(z) = \frac {1}{1+z^2} $ and use above identity:

$$\frac {1}{1+z^2} = \frac {1}{1-(-z^2)} $$
But observe that I need to center it at $z_0=1$ so I rewrote it to:

$$\frac {1}{1-(-z^2)}=\frac {1}{2z-(-(z-1)^2)} $$

I can factor out $\frac {1}{2z}$ and use the basic identity to get :
$$\frac {1}{2z}\frac {1}{1-\frac{(z-1)^2}{2z}} = \frac {1}{2z}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{-(z-1)^2}{2z}\right)^n =\frac {1}{2z}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n(z-1)^{2n}}{(2z)^n} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n(z-1)^{2n}}{(2z)^{n+1}}$$

The problem is if I ask wolfram alpha: power series$ \frac{1}{1+z^2} $centered at z = 1 it will give me a different answer that doesn't match the sum I found.

Can anyone help me figure this one out? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like you made a mistake on the beginning of your last equation. When you factored out $2z$, apparently you missed a minus sign, correct?

Comment: Yes I did miss a minus sign thanks :) hopefully its corrected.

Comment: @Element118 - my wolframalpha input is 1/(1+z^2) not 1/(1-z^2)

Comment: I don't think you are allowed to keep $z$, except as part of $z-1$.

Comment: @Michael - is that true? :O.. do you have any pointers what method might be used in this case?

Comment: Also you should not have $z$ in the denominator.

Comment: Also, according to your question, you asked Wolfram for the power series of $\dfrac{1}{1-z^2}$ but your questions is about $\dfrac{1}{1+z^2}$, which explains why Wolfram's result is different. Apparently, fixing the minus sign I said, it will be correct!

Comment: @Element118 Yes I can see on the wolfram output that the series do not contain any z in the denominator.. I'm at lost as to how to proceed

Comment: @Hamsteriffic Thanks for the catch :) typo on my part.. I still don't get the correct result on wolfram alpha.. I asked a math professor and he told me the algebraic operations I have done are correct.. yet I feel I am missing something important.. cant figure it out

Comment: Your series is no power series.

Comment: @gammatester now that would be something :O... my math book asks me to write the function as a power series though.. hmm

Comment: Yeah, I think @gammatester summarized it. Your series seems to be correct, it doesn't match Wolfram's series because your series is not a power series. This doesn't mean your series is wrong - it's just different, and not a power series.

Comment: @Hamsteriffic Hmm.. I can buy that. But what characterizes a power series.. and what would I need to know in order to write the function as a power series?

Comment: A power series is something like $\sum a_n(z - z_0)^n$ - your series has $z$ in the denominator as well, and that is not allowed for a power series :) as for the way to write the function as a power series, you would have to use some other trick, like the one suggested by Michael in his answer.

Comment: @Hamsteriffic thanks, I seem to have more research to do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac1{1+z^2}=\frac1{(z-1)^2+2(z-1)+2}\\
=\frac12\left(1+(z-1)+\frac12(z-1)^2\right)^{-1}\\
=\frac12\left(1-((z-1)+\frac12(z-1)^2)+((z-1)+\frac12(z-1)^2)^2-...\right)\\
=\frac12-\frac12(z-1)+\frac14(z-1)^2+0(z-1)^3+...$$

Comment: I understand what you are doing up to 90% but I don't see what identity you are applying to get the series.. I'm used to writing them in the form 1/(1-z)

Comment: I expanded the series.  The next term is $-((z-1)+\frac12(z-1)^2)^3$, which has $(z-1)^3,(z-1)^4,(z-1)^5$ and $(z-1)^6$ terms in it.  So I picked out the $(z-1)^3$ term from there, and the $(z-1)^3$ term in the middle of $((z-1)+\frac12(z-1)^2)^2$.

Comment: Is there an easy way to write this with the sum (sigma) notation without having to expand the series?

Comment: Thanks I finally understood what is happening. I also found the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{1+z^2}
&=\frac1{2+2w+w^2}\tag1\\[9pt]
&=\frac1{2i}\frac1{1-i+w}-\frac1{2i}\frac1{1+i+w}\tag2\\[6pt]
&=\frac{1-i}4\frac1{1+\frac{1+i}2w}+\frac{1+i}4\frac1{1+\frac{1-i}2w}\tag3\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}4\left[\left(\frac{1+i}2\right)^{k-1}+\left(\frac{1-i}2\right)^{k-1}\right](z-1)^k\tag4\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(-\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)^k\cos\left(\frac{\pi(k-1)}4\right)(z-1)^k\tag5
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: substitute $z=w+1$
$(2)$: partial fractions
$(3)$: use the forms $\frac1{1+aw}$ for easier series
$(4)$: write $\frac1{1+aw}$ as geometric series and undo $(1)$
$(5)$: convert to cosines

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately (irresponsibly?), the "answer" was accepted, and newer questions about the same series are  closed as duplicates (by people having more privileges than judgement). Just in case some naive people follow the link to this old turkey, let's post something deserving the name "answer" (hopefully).

If you look for a power *series*, you don't need just the first three terms without much of an explanation, you need an algorithm how to compute as many coefficients as you need, or, if possible, an explicit formula.

So let's have a look at $$\frac1{1+x^2}=\frac1{2+2\,(x-1)+(x-1)^2}=\sum^\infty_{n=0}a_n\,(x-1)^n:$$ Multiplying both sides by the denominator and comparing equal powers of $x-1$, we get $$2\,a_0=1,$$ $$2\,a_1+2\,a_0=0$$ and
$$2\,a_n+2\,a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}=0$$ for $n\ge2$. That means $$a_0=1/2,$$ $$a_1=-1/2$$
and $$a_n=-a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}/2\tag{Recursion}$$ for $n\ge2$, allowing to calculate as many coefficients as needed. Of course, this gives the same values $a_2=1/4$ and $a_3=0$, but you can continue that ad nauseam, without much effort.

If you want an explicit formula for $a_n$, there are several ways, each opening another can of worms. You could solve (Recursion), that's not so hard because of the constant coefficients, but boring. Or you could recognize the generating function of Chebyshev polynomials of second kind, $$\frac1{1-2\,t\,y+t^2}=\sum^\infty_{n=0}U_n(y)\,t^n.$$ Since $$\frac1{2+2\,(x-1)+(x-1)^2}=\frac12\,\frac1{1-2\cdot\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\frac{x-\,1}{\sqrt{2}}+\left(\frac{x-1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2},$$ we see that
$$\frac1{1+x^2}=\frac12\,\sum^\infty_{n=0}\,U_n\left(\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\,\left(\frac{x-1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^n.$$
From the trigonometric definition, we have $$U_n(\cos\theta)=\frac{\sin (n+1)\theta}{\sin\theta},$$ and since $$\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}=\cos\frac{3\pi}4,$$ we have $$U_n\left(\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)=\sqrt{2}\,\sin\frac{3(n+1)\pi}4,$$ i.e.
$$a_n=\frac{\sin\frac{3(n+1)\pi}4}{2^{\frac{n+1}2}}.$$
Those infos about Chebyshev polynomials can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials

Yet another possibility would be to use
$$\frac1{1+x^2}=\frac1{2i}\left(\frac1{x-i}-\frac1{x+i}\right)$$ and the good old geometric series, but that (if you know complex numbers) would give the same explicit formula for $a_n$, naturally.