# Power series of $\frac{1}{1+x^{2}}$ centered at $x=1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I have to find the power series of
$$\frac{1}{1+x^{2}}$$
centered at $a=1$.

So, I tried to write it as
$$\frac{1}{1-(-(x-1)^{2})}$$
to sue the fact that
$$\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{n}$$
Since $1-(-(x-1)^{2})=1+x^{2}-2x+1$, then what I did next was:
$$\frac{1}{1+x^{2}}=\frac{1}{1+x^{2}-2x+1+2x-1}=\frac{1}{1+(x-1)^{2}+2x-1}=\frac{1}{2x+(x-1)^{2}}$$
My question is: what am I supposed to do after this?

I also thought about doing something like:
$$\frac{1}{1+x^{2}}=\frac{1}{1+x^{2}-2x+1+2x-1}=\frac{1}{1+(x-1)^{2}+2x-1}=\frac{1}{(1+(x-1)^{2})+(2x-1)}$$
and then, using partial fractions, try to finish it.

Comment: Just a quick note which may help you $\frac{1}{1+x^2}=\frac{1}{1-(-x^2)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nx^{2n}$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Write $\frac {1}{1+z^2}$ as a power series centered at $z_0=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1569168/write-frac-11z2-as-a-power-series-centered-at-z-0-1)

Comment: @A. E. Rosas That "answer" gives only the first few terms, without much of an explanation. IMHO, "find the power series" means to find the general term, or at least an algorithm to compute as many coefficients as needed.

Comment: Since people with sufficient privileges in their infinite wisdom closed this question, I have to post an answer deserving that name in the linked question, no matter how old it is.